# Java: How does ThreadFactory handles Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm currently using the ***default ThreadFactory*** and I'm not satisfied with it's performance and queueing of tasks. As I searched about **ThreadFactory**, I want to consider it's implementation.

My question is that does **ThreadFactory** automatically shutdown it's *Threads* under in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ThreadFactory` has a single method, [`newThread(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html#newThread-java.lang.Runnable-), which

> Constructs a new Thread.

It does not manage the lifecycle of the thread, so, no, it doesn't shutdown any thread.

Comment: If ThreadFactory doesn't manage lifecycle of threads, how will I manage it if it is under the ThreadFactory?

Comment: @EriezeLagera, There is nothing _under_ ThreadFactory.  A call to  `Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r)` doesn't do anything different from a call to Thread.new(r).

Comment: @EriezeLagera, Here's what ThreadFactory is for:  If I design a library that needs to create new threads, and you have an application that needs all threads to be created in a certain way (e.g., they must all be named according to a certain rule); Then I can provide a means for your app to pass a ThreadFactory in to my library,  That way, my library will use _your_ ThreadFactory to create all of the threads that it needs, and all of the threads will be created in accordance with _your_ policy.

Comment: @jameslarge Correct me if I'm wrong, so ThreadFactory is just a collection of Threads that is waiting to be used? (eg. thru Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory());)

Comment: @EriezeLagera `ThreadFactory` is an interface. Implementations simply create new threads. How that is managed is up to the implementation. It's the `ExecutorService` types returned by `Executors` method that pool those threads, not the `DefaultThreadFactory`.